# Play Framework 2.3 pass/inject templates as parameters of other templates in the controller level

Tags: templates, playframework-2.3, inject

Is it possible to inject templates into other templates in Play Framework at Controller level?

I have:

```
Ok(views.html.staticpages.index("Your new application is ready.")(views.html.shared.header.unauthenticatedheader()))
```

but it gives me the error:

Type mismatch, expected Html, actual Any

when trying to pass views.html.shared.header.unauthenticated to [...].index, index receives a header: Html as the second argument, when playing with passing templates into another templates at template level this is normal to pass an Html type, but is it possible to transform the header.unauthenticated to a Html type?

These are the headers of my templates:

header.unathenticatedheader:

```
@()(implicit request: common.request.CanBeAuthenticatedRequest[_])
```

staticpages.index:

```
@import common.request.CanBeAuthenticatedRequest

@(title: String = "Welcome to Play")(header: Html)(implicit request: CanBeAuthenticatedRequest[_])
```

Comment: My local version of this is working fine - can you post the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: @SteveChaloner I have added the headers of my templates, let me know if you need something else, the request type "CanBeAuthenticatedRequest" is passed to the index template as well and when the index template did not need the header parameter, it worked so I think the custom WrappedRequest is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of choices here.  You can pass in the result of rendering, or you can pass in the template and have it render itself within the template.

If you need to pass parameters into the templates, you might be better passing in the result; if you pass in parameterless templates, it's personal preference.

**Pass in the result**

Template:

```
@(message: String)(myInsert: Html)

<div>start: @message</div>
<div> @myInsert </div>
<div>end</div>
```

Controller:

```
def index = Action {
  Ok(views.html.index("foo")(views.html.insert()))
}
```

**Pass in the template**

Template:

```
@(message: String)(myInsert: Template0[play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable])

<div>start @message</div>
<div> @myInsert.render() </div>
<div>end</div>
```

Controller:

```
def index = Action {
  Ok(views.html.index2("sdf sdf d")(views.html.insert2))
}
```

Comment: Mmmm... the "Pass in the result" option is what I want but I don't see where is the difference between your code and my code

Comment: You're definitely declaring an `implicit request` in your controller action?

Comment: Yes, sure. It is working now. I've had to restart activator. Thanks for your interest!